# CATIA 3DX VBA creation of new assembly with exisitng products from 3DX database

Tags: vba, catia

I'm new to VBA in 3DExperience Catia. I'm looking for a snippet with reference macro code for creating new assembly and adding existing products from 3DExperience database. The best would be to create constrain between these products but I'll be happy with any advice for now.

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this task myself.

Please check post below to see my conclusion.

[Insert part to assembly in 3DEXPERIENCE macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64439571/insert-part-to-assembly-in-3dexperience-macro/64714799#64714799)